# Update a array out side handlechange function React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an handlechange function

```
const [values, SetValues] = useState({
    addrId: "",
    addrType: "",
    addrLine1: "",
    addrLine2: "",
    countryId: "",
    stateId: "",
    countyId: "",
    zip: "",
  });

 const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    SetValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

I tried to update some field(countryID) using other functions say handleAnotherFunction

```
const handleAnotherFunction=async(event)=>
 {
 SetValues({ ...values, [values.countryId]: 130 });
}
```

But value is not updated any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you mean `countryId: 130` only to set the `countryId` property to 130?

Comment: @JakubKotrs yes i want to update countryID as 130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax:

```
[name]: value
```

uses the *value* of the *variable* `name` as the object key.  So, for example, if `name` has the value `"foo"` then it creates or updates the key `foo` to the value of `value`:

```
foo: 'some value'
```

So, when you use this same syntax:

```
[values.countryId]: 130
```

It uses the *value* of `values.countryId` as the object key.  So if that *value* is, for example, `100` then you're adding a key to the object called `100` and giving it the value `130`:

```
100: 130
```

If you want to explicitly update the field `countryId`, just use `countryId`:

```
countryId: 130
```

So the whole line would be:

```
SetValues({ ...values, countryId: 130 });
```

Comment: i tried this but value not update.got previous value only

Comment: @Shanukk: This [demonstrably works](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-meadow-j9yi9c?file=/src/App.js).  It's entirely possible that your code has *some other problem* though.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem(s)?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to update some field(countryID) using other functions

so what's the purpose of creating `handleChange` ?

The `handleChange` in your code is designed to update the state based on the given value as parameter. 
it destructs the key and the value from the property `target` of the given object then updates the state. so if you want to update the property `countyId` all you have to do is to call `handleChange` :

```js
handleChange({target:{name: "countyId", value: 130}})
```